# Vuetify VIcon doesn't show up in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, storybook

I'm developing a **Vue** app with **Vuetify** and also document the components with **Storybook**.

I'm writing the stories nicely, all components seem to show up in **Storybook** (like my custom components & the **Vuetify** components too). Except for **VIcon**.

I have a component that uses **Vuetify**'s **VIcon**, and I couldn't get the icon to show up (in the real app there's no problem with that).

The setup:

**src/plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
  }
});
```

**.storybook/vuetify_storybook.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'; // loads all components
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'; // all the css for components
import config from '@/plugins/vuetify'; // basic config with theme

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify(config);
```

**.storybook/preview.js**

```
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/vue';
import vuetify from './vuetify_storybook';

addDecorator(() => ({
  vuetify,
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <story />
    </v-app>
    `,
}));
```

**.storybook/main.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../stories/**/*.stories.js',
    '../src/**/*.stories.js'
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs',
    '@storybook/addon-storysource'
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {

    config.resolve.extensions.push('.vue', '.css', '.less', '.scss', '.sass', '.html')

    // Use Sass loader for vuetify components
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.sass$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            additionalData: "@import '@/styles/variables.scss';"
          }
        }
      ],
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
          'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',          
        },
      },
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

**CustomVIcon.stories.js**

```
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'

export default {
  title: 'Display that icon',
  decorators: [withKnobs]
}

export const displayIcon = () => {
  return {
    template: `<v-icon>mdi-alert</v-icon>`
  }
}
```

If I add a text that is not an **mdi icon** (like `<v-icon>notmditext</v-icon>`, then the text is displayed - but as soon as I add a **-** (dash/minus sign) to the string, it doesn't show up.

I can see the icon's HTML (well, part of it) in the console, only the `::before` part is missing (that should be the actual icon). So styles are set, classes are added, etc when I inspect the Storybook page (where the icon should be).

- Already tried adding `https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-addon-jsx` (as in the real case the component is rendered with JSX), nothing changed (no `v-icon`)
- Already tried putting other components in the story (like `VCard`), and they showed up (and other stories work just perfectly)
- **Vue** is 2.6.12, **Vuetify** 2.3.10, **@storybook/vue** 6.0.21 - so quite fresh
- Also tried to import components from `vuetify/lib` (and not just `vuetify)` in the `.storybook/vuetify_storybook.js` & registering them locally (in the `preview.js` and the story file - no change)

Comment: might be a long shot, but is it possible some other CSS is setting the `content` property of your `:before` to `none`? Because that would effectively remove them which kind of forbids inspection. As a test, you could set the before's `content` property with `!important` and see if it renders. That will allow you to inspect the element and therefore see where the `none` (now overridden) is coming from. Is there any chance you could set up a [mcve]?

Comment: @tao thanks for the idea - unfortunately I couldn't have set it by hand, as Vuetify "hides" this. I tried to think of creating a **minimal, reproducible example**, but it could've taken serious time to do that, so I kept it only for last resort (setting up EVERYTHING as in my dev environment AND reducing the problem... Vue, Vuetify, Storybook, link them together, etc.... Ahhhh :) ). But if no idea had come for cca. two-three days, then I would've done it. Anyways - thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

OK, just needed another view on the things:

- removed the link to the Material design icons CDN:

```
// remove this from public/index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
```

- changed the package from `@mdi/js` to `@mdi/font`

```
npm remove @mdi/js
npm install @mdi/font -D
```

- imported the corresponding CSS in two places:

```
// add this to src/main.js & .storybook/vuetify_storybook.js
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
```

- changed the **Vuetify** config

```
// in src/plugins/vuetify.js
icons: {
  // iconfont: 'mdiSvg', // change this
  iconfont: 'mdi', // to this
},
```

AND VOILÁ! **VIcon** shows up.

So, the problem was that I thought everything had been set up correctly, but it wasn't the case: the icons in the app were coming from the CDN (have not looked at the **Network** tab), and when I removed the CDN link from the `index.html` it immediately became apparent.

More on setting up the icons in **Vuetify**: [Install Material Design Icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#install-material-design-icons)